# Bounding the derivative of a holomorphic function on a disk by its absolute value

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function defined on the disk $|z|\le 2$. Suppose $|f(z)|<1$ for $|z|\le 2$. It looks like there is a constant $c>0$ such that $|f(z)'|<c$ on the disk $|z|\le 1$ (for example, $c=1$?). I wonder if this is true. If yes, is an optimal such constant can be found?

Comment: Cauchy integral formula gives $\lvert f'(z)\rvert\leq 2$ (integrate over a circle centered at 0, of radius $2-\varepsilon $). This is certainly not optimal.

Comment: The optimal inequality should be the one you get from the invariant form of the Schwarz lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

Comment: If you rescale so that your big disk is $|z|<1$ and the small one is $|z|<1/2$, then this gives $c=4/3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. The simple reason is that bounded functions form a normal family. Therefore their derivatives are uniformly bounded on every compact.

To obtain the estimate $|f'(z)|<1$, apply Cauchy theorem:
$$|f'(z)|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|\zeta-z|=1}\frac{f(\zeta) d\zeta}{(\zeta-z)^2}\right|\leq 1.$$
Equality in the right inequality can happen only if $f$ is constant, so we always have a strict inequality.

So this estimate is not exact. 
To obtain the exact one, 
follow @Christian Remling's suggestion and use the Schwarz lemma. For convenience, let $g(z)=f(2z)$, then
$g$ maps the unit disk into itself, so 
$$|g'(z)|\leq \frac{1-|g(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}\leq\frac{1}{1-|z|^2}\leq \frac{4}{3}.$$
Thus the exact estimate us $|f'(z)|=|g'(z)|/2\leq 2/3.$ This is attained on
a Mobius map.

Comment: I don't understand your final statement. Isn't it obvious from my comment above that $|f'(z)|$ is maximized by the Mobius transformations that send $z\mapsto 0$ ?

Comment: @Christian Remling: Of course, but when you rescale the derivative changes by a factor of $2$.

Comment: The "final statement" I was referring to was the final statement when I wrote my comment, before your edit.